# discord.js (v14) ban command, error when verifying roles

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

The ban command doesn't work when the bot has to verify the highest role of the user.
This is the code

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder, PermissionFlagsBits, EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const yaml = require('js-yaml');
const cmdconfig = yaml.load(fs.readFileSync('./commands.yml'));
const serverLanguage = require('../../Schemas/serverLanguage');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName(cmdconfig.ban)
        .setDescription(cmdconfig.banDesc)
        .addUserOption(option =>
            option.setName(cmdconfig.banUserOption)
            .setDescription(cmdconfig.banUserOptionDesc)
            .setRequired(true)    
        )
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName(cmdconfig.banReasonOption)
            .setDescription(cmdconfig.banReasonOptionDesc)
            .setRequired(false)
        )
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName(cmdconfig.banDMOption)
            .setDescription(cmdconfig.banDMOptionDesc)
            .setRequired(false)
            .addChoices(
                { name: 'True', value: 'true' },
                { name: 'False', value: 'false' }
            )
        ),

    async execute(interaction, client){
        const { options, guild } = interaction;

        const languageDataDB = await serverLanguage.findOne({ Guild: guild.id })
        let language;

        if(!languageDataDB){
            language = 'english'
        } else {
            language = languageDataDB.Language
        }

        const languageStrings = require(`../../Languages/Strings/${language}.json`);
        const languageEmbeds = require(`../../Languages/Embeds/${language}.json`);
        const permissionsNamesLanguages = require(`../../Languages/PermissionsNames/${language}.json`);

        if(!interaction.member.permissions.has(PermissionFlagsBits.BanMembers)) return interaction.reply(`${languageStrings.noPermissionsForCommand} \`${permissionsNamesLanguages.BanMembers}\``)

        const user = options.getUser(cmdconfig.banUserOption);
        const reason = options.getString(cmdconfig.banReasonOption) || languageStrings.NoReasonGiven;
        const DMuser = options.getString(cmdconfig.banDMOption) || false;

        const userToBan = guild.members.cache.get(user.id)

        if(userToBan == client.user.id) return interaction.reply(languageStrings.banUserIsTheBotCommand)
        if(userToBan == interaction.user.id) return interaction.reply(languageStrings.banUserIsExecutorCommand)
        if(!userToBan) return interaction.reply(languageStrings.banUserNotFoundCommand)
        if(!userToBan?.bannable) return interaction.reply(languageStrings.banUserNotBannableCommand)
        if(userToBan.id == guild.ownerId) return interaction.reply(languageStrings.banUserIsTheGuildOwnerCommand)

        const executorRolePosition = interaction.member.roles.highest.position;
        const userToBanRolePosition = userToBan.roles.highest.position;
        if(userToBanRolePosition >= executorRolePosition) return interaction.reply(languageStrings.banNoEnoughRolesCommand)

        const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor('Green')
            .setDescription(languageEmbeds.banDescriptionCommand1)
            .setThumbnail(userToBan.displayAvatarURL())
            .addFields(
                { name: languageEmbeds.banUserFieldCommand, value: `${userToBan}` },
                { name: languageEmbeds.banReasonFieldCommand, value: `${reason}` }
            )

        const DmEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor('Red')
            .setDescription(`${languageEmbeds.banDescriptionCommand2} **${guild.name}**`)
            .setThumbnail(guild.iconURL())
            .addFields(
                { name: languageEmbeds.banReasonFieldCommand, value: reason }
            )

        let dmUserNotSucceed;
        if(DMuser == 'true'){
            try{
                const dmChannel = await userToBan.createDM();
                await dmChannel.send({ embeds: [DmEmbed] })
            } catch(error) {
                console.log(error)
                dmUserNotSucceed = true
            }
        }

        await userToBan.ban({ reason: `Banned by ${interaction.user.username}: ${reason}`});
        await interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] });
        if(DMuser == 'true' && dmUserNotSucceed == true) interaction.followUp(languageStrings.banDmError);

    }
}
```

When I try to ban a user with highest roles than me it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'position')
    at Object.execute (D:\Matteo\Bot Discord\AnotherBot\Commands\Moderation\ban.js:63:34)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Object.execute (D:\Matteo\Bot Discord\AnotherBot\Events\interactionCreate.js:16:13)
```

I tried searching for a tutorial on YouTube but I literally pasted that part of the code (where it verifies the highest roles of the user)

Comment: Which version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: I'm using discord.js v14

Comment: There's easy work-around, that you can just also add for a bot higher position role, then wrap this code up with try-catch block and outputing with catch if the bot finds the error (if it won't be able to ban a user, since the position mismatch)